# python re module, найти все теги

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Если мне приходит строкой структура `html` файла,

Для примера

```
<div>
 <p><a>Example one</a></p>
 <p><a>Example two</a></p>
</div>
```

как я могу вытянуть два `<a>Example one</a>` и `<a>Example two</a>` тега?
через `re` модуль. Спасибо

Comment: `re.findall` и `(<a>.+?</a>)`

Comment: Спасибо, работает! А можно с тегов вытянуть информацию? через `re`? и если у вас есть хороший ресурс где можно подтянуть `regex` буду очень блогадорен

Comment: Можно, но обработкой html/xml лучше заниматься соответствующими инструментами - парсерами, например: lxml, beautifulsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

text = """\
<div>
 <p><a>Example one</a></p>
 <p><a>Example two</a></p>
</div>
"""

print(re.findall(r'(<a>.+?</a>)', text))
```

Консоль:

```
['<a>Example one</a>', '<a>Example two</a>']
```